# Smarty and gettext plugin doesnt work every time

Tags: smarty, gettext

We are using the localization using Smarty gettext plugin and it works fine on the local server. Though on production server ( Linux Debian ) sometimes the translations are correct and sometimes not.

I mean we have some internal URLs in popup iframes and it sometimes work and sometimes doesnt. I have checked all solution posted on Stack Overflow and not succeeded.

my code is something like this

```
putenv("LANGUAGE=nl_NL.UTF-8");
$domain = 'mydomain';
bindtextdomain($domain, "./locale"); 
textdomain($domain);
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
setlocale(LC_ALL, array('nl_NL.UTF-8','nl_NL@euro','nl_NL','dutch'));
```

Comment: When you say "not working", you need to be clearer what actually happens. Do the translations sometimes get shown in the "wrong" language? Have you been able to spot any patterns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your problem is with calls to `setlocale` on different page loads interrupting each other.

PHP, when running under many common server set-ups (e.g. Apache mod_php under a threaded worker model) is not inherently "thread-safe"; unfortunately, neither is the underlying C function which `setlocale` wraps.

Between calling `setlocale` and actually outputting some content, a different thread within the same process can therefore get control of the CPU and also call `setlocale`; once the first thread regains control and generates some output, the locale setting is lost.

The solution is either to configure your server to use a non-threaded execution model (e.g. Apache's "pre-fork MPM") or change the code to use a different locale mechanism which is thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks this was fixed yes it was different page load issue